# Como quitar los Domingos en un rango de fechas en Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Quisiera saber  si existe alguna forma en `mysql` de quitar los domingos de un rango de fechas  es decir

> `Fecha inicIal : 2017-08-01  ( Y-m-d)`
>   `Fecha Final :  2017-08-31  ( Y-m-d)`

cantidad de días : `31`
 cantidad de domingos : `4`
 total : `27`

Tambien Saber la cantidad de Dias que contiene un mes   apartir de una fecha
es decir

> `Fecha inicIal : 2017-08-01  ( Y-m-d)`

cantidad de días : `31`

Comment: En [stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1804095/4734392) respondieron esta pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: @MatíasDell'Oso Aunque este contestada allá, se busca que este sitio crezca con sus propias respuestas. También esta contestada en la documentación de MySql y seguro en varias paginas mas. No por eso vamos a mandar todas las preguntas (que casi seguro están contestadas en ingles) al sitio en ingles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu pregunta es muy interesante y puede derivar en otras cómo ¿cuántos sábados hay en un intervalo? o ¿cuantos días hábiles hay en el mismo?. Hay varias formas de resolverlo, en principio se me ocurre la siguiente basada en el calculo de múltiplos. Veamos:

Supongamos lo siguiente: queremos contar cuantos domingos hay entre el 7/8/2017  (lunes y el  21/8/2017 (también lunes). Por empezar son 15 días en total y el primero es un lunes, por lo que si consideramos el lunes como el día 1, los días del rango (contando desde la fecha desde) los podemos ver como el siguiente conjunto:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
```

En este rango, dónde el lunes es el número 1 en la semana, el domingo es el 7, y ubicar el domingo es tan simple como calcular los múltiplos de 7. El calculo efectivo es: la parte entera de la división 15 / 7 = 2. Efectivamente hay 2 domingos (los días 7 y 14).

El único caso que rompe esta estrategia es cuando el límite inferior ya es un domingo, entonces en 15 días, en vez de tener 2 domingos vamos a tener 3, por ejemplo, en la siguiente lista de días de la semana (del 6/8/2017 al 20/8/2017), si consideramos el día de la semana de cada uno y arrancamos del 7 (domingo) sería así:

```
7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21
```

Siguen siendo 15 días pero hay tres múltiplos de 7: 7, 14, 21 es decir 3 domingos, por lo que deberemos ajustar este caso a la lógica inicial

```
SET @FromDate      = '2017-08-01';
SET @ToDate        = '2017-08-31';
SET @DiaSemana     = 7; -- 7 domingo, 1 lunes
SET @Minimo        = CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(@FromDate)-1 = 0 THEN 7 ELSE DAYOFWEEK(@FromDate)-1 END;

SELECT datediff(@ToDate, @FromDate) DIV 7 + (CASE WHEN @Minimo = @DiaSemana THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'CantDias';
```

El retorno:

```
CantDias
========
4
```

Los más importante de todo es calcular el día de la semana del límite inferior `@Minimo` como `DAYOFWEEK` considera que el domingo es el día uno, hay que ajustarlo para que sea el 7. Configurando `@DiaSemana` se puede contar cualquiera de los días.

Por otro lado, para saber la cantidad de días entre dos fechas, puedes usar la función [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) que ya hemos usado, por ejemplo:

```
datediff(@ToDate, @FromDate)
```

En nuestro ejemplo nos devolverá `31` días, luego con una simple resta podemos quedarnos sin los domingos y concluir que hay 27 días hábiles. Y si quieres saber cuantos días restan para llegar a fin de mes, usando [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) ontenemos el último día del mes dada una fecha, y con [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) podremos obtener la catidad de días que restan para el fin de mes, por ejemplo:

```
datediff(LAST_DAY(@FromDate),@FromDate)
```

Answer (score 5):

La funcion `DAYOFWEEK(date)` recibe una fecha como parametro, y devuelve un numero que indica el dia. Segun la documentacion, la numeracion es la siguiente:

1. Domingo
2. Lunes

...

7. Sabado

Con lo cual, una consulta simple podria tener una clausula de exclusion similar a la siguiente:

```
Where DAYOFWEEK(fecha) <> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Para el primer caso, calcular el número de días entre dos fechas excepto domingos se puede hacer restando un día por cada 7 días de una semana, y uno más si comienza en domingo, estableciendo el resultado en función de que cumpla o no la condición. Hay que tener en cuenta que al utilizar la función de diferencia tiene en cuenta la diferencia y no el total de días, por lo que debe corregirse el dato sumando un día.

```
SELECT IF (DAYOFWEEK(FECHA_INICIO)=1,
    FLOOR(DATEDIFF(FECHA_FIN, FECHA_INICIO)) - FLOOR((DATEDIFF(FECHA_FIN, FECHA_INICIO)/7)),
    FLOOR(DATEDIFF(FECHA_FIN, FECHA_INICIO)) - FLOOR((DATEDIFF(FECHA_FIN, FECHA_INICIO)/7))+1
) AS TOTAL
FROM MITABLA
```

La segunda pregunta, número de días desde una fecha hasta el fin de mes, se puede resolver calculando el último día del mes para una fecha con `LAST_DAY` y la diferencia entre ambos:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(FECHA_INICIO),
DATEDIFF(LAST_DAY(FECHA_INICIO),FECHA_INICIO)
FROM MI_TABLA
```

En este último caso, para calcular el número de días de un mes en el que se encuentra una determinada fecha puedes utilizar `DAY(LAST_DAY(FECHA))`.

Comment: Carmen, tu idea es válida, pero revisa la implementación ya que tiene algún problema. Verificando `20170801` a `20170831` me dice que hay 25 días. Cuando agosto tiene 31 días y 4 domingos..

Comment: Tenías razón @PatricioMoracho, ya está corregido y comprobado.